# Which is the best way that Apache Spark DStream joins with static data records from the HDFS sequence file?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, streaming, sequence

My goal is to monitor user input using SparkStreaming. The user's input is DStream and is just a key to data record (short string). The program needs filter and read the static data set (very big RDD, bigRDD) from HDFS Sequence File (a single record 30MB, the entire data set is about 10,000 records) by the user-entered key value. Then the program calculates the bigRDD and return the result records (30MB each) to the user. I hope that the calculation of bigRDD will be distributed locally as much as possible, avoid data transmission on the network, and use persist to reduce hard disk IO time. How should the specific steps be designed? 
I tried:

```
JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(...) ;
JavaDStream<String> lines = jsc.socketTextStream(...) ;
seqRDD = jsc.sparkContext().sequenceFile(...);// RDD from sequence file can not cache.
bigRDD = pairRdd.mapToPair(...) ;// bigRDD is used for cache.
bigRDD.cache() ;
inputDStream = lines.mapToPair(...) ; // convert DStream<string> to PairDStream<string,string> for join.
inputDStream.foreachRDD (inputRdd-> {
  bigRDD2 = inputRdd.join(bigRDD);
  resultRDD = bigRDD2.map( ... do calculation ... );
  send_result_to_user(resultRDD) ;
})
```

But I don't know if those steps are appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I will try broadcast the data from DStream.RDD.collection() every batch and use RDD mapPartitions to process the data.